# Compute sum (infinite series)

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Compute the sum
>   $$
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n-1)!}{(n+k)!}
> $$
>   where $k = 1,2,\ldots$ is fixed.

I was able to compute the sum of a simpler infinite series:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{n(n+1)(n+2)}
$$
In that case, my given hint was to notice that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 2{n(n+1)(n+2)} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac 1{n(n+1)}-\frac 1{(n+1)(n+2)} \right)
$$
is a telescoping series.

How can I find a telescoping series for the generalized sum above?

Comment: Hint: look at what terms "vanish" from the denominator when you go from the original series to the telescoping one. If you are still stuck, try doing it for $k=3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{n - 1}! \over \pars{n + k}!}\quad}$ where
>   $\ds{\quad k = 1,2,\ldots}$ is *fixed*.

Lets
$\ds{\,\mrm{f}\pars{x} \equiv
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{n - 1}! \over \pars{n + k}!}\,x^{n}\quad}$
where $\ds{\quad x \in \pars{0,1}\quad}$ and 
$\ds{\color{#f00}{\quad\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{n - 1}! \over \pars{n + k}!}} = \mrm{f}\pars{1^{-}}}$.

---

\begin{align}
x\,\mrm{f}'\pars{x} &\equiv
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{n - 1}! \over \pars{n + k}!}\,n\,x^{n} =
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{n - 1}! \over \pars{n + k - 1}!}\,\,x^{n} -
k\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{n - 1}! \over \pars{n + k}!}\,\,x^{n}
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{n! \over \pars{n + k}!}\,\,x^{n + 1} -
k\,\mrm{f}\pars{x} =
{x \over k!} +
x^{2}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{n - 1}! \over \pars{n + k}!}\,n\,x^{n - 1} -k\,\mrm{f}\pars{x}
\\[5mm] & =
{x \over k!} + x^{2}\,\mrm{f}'\pars{x} -k\,\mrm{f}\pars{x} \implies
\pars{x^{2} - x}\mrm{f}'\pars{x} - k\,\mrm{f}\pars{x} = -\,{x \over k!}
\\[5mm] \implies &
\bbox[8px,border:0.1em groove navy]{
\mrm{f}'\pars{x} - {k \over x^{2} - x}\,\mrm{f}\pars{x} =
{1 \over k!}\,{1 \over 1 - x}\,,\quad\mrm{f}\pars{0^{+}} = 0}
\end{align}

---

The above differential equation can be rewritten as:
\begin{align}
&\totald{\bracks{x^{k}\pars{1 - x}^{-k}\,\mrm{f}\pars{x}}}{x} =
{1 \over k!}\,\pars{1 - x}^{-k - 1}x^{k}
\\[5mm] &\ \implies\bbox[8px,border:0.1em groove navy]{
\mrm{f}\pars{x} = {1 \over k!}\,x^{-k}\pars{1 - x}^{k}
\int_{0}^{x}\pars{1 - t}^{-k - 1}t^{k}\,\dd t\,,\qquad x \in \pars{0,1}}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\quad\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{n - 1}! \over \pars{n + k}!}} & =
\lim_{x \to 1^{-}}\bracks{%
{1 \over k!}\,x^{-k}\pars{1 - x}^{k}\int_{0}^{x}\pars{1 - t}^{-k - 1}t^{k}
\,\dd t} =
{1 \over k!}\,\lim_{x \to 1^{-}}
\bracks{{\pars{1 - x}^{-k - 1}x^{k} \over k\pars{1 - x}^{-k - 1}}}
\\[5mm] & =
\color{#f00}{1 \over k\,\, k!}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

---

For $m\in\mathbb{N}$, define the sequence $s:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ via the infinite series

$$s_{m}:=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(n-1\right)!}{\left(m+n\right)!}.$$

Note that for each nonnegative integer $n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$, we can express the factorial $n!$ in terms of the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) with the relation

$$n!=\Gamma{\left(n+1\right)}.$$

A related function known as the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) may be defined via the integral representation

$$\operatorname{B}{\left(a,b\right)}:=\int_{0}^{1}t^{a-1}\left(1-t\right)^{b-1}\,\mathrm{d}t;~~~\small{a>0\land b>0}.$$

The beta function can be reduced to gamma functions through the following identity:

$$\operatorname{B}{\left(a,b\right)}=\frac{\Gamma{\left(a\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(b\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(a+b\right)}}.$$

---

Now, for each positive integer $m\in\mathbb{N}$, we find using the technique of summing under the integral sign that

$$\begin{align}
s_{m}
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(n-1\right)!}{\left(m+n\right)!}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{k!}{\left(m+k+1\right)!}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma{\left(k+1\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(m+k+2\right)}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\Gamma{\left(m+1\right)}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma{\left(k+1\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(m+1\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(m+k+2\right)}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\Gamma{\left(m+1\right)}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\operatorname{B}{\left(k+1,m+1\right)}\\
&=\frac{1}{\Gamma{\left(m+1\right)}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}t^{k}\left(1-t\right)^{m}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac{1}{\Gamma{\left(m+1\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}t^{k}\left(1-t\right)^{m}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac{1}{\Gamma{\left(m+1\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\left(1-t\right)^{m}}{1-t}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac{1}{\Gamma{\left(m+1\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}x^{m-1}\,\mathrm{d}x;~~~\small{\left[1-t=x\right]}\\
&=\frac{1}{\Gamma{\left(m+1\right)}}\cdot\frac{1}{m}\\
&=\frac{1}{m!\,m}.\blacksquare\\
\end{align}$$

---

Answer (score 0):

*This is not an answer but it is too long for a comment.*

Considering the partial sums $$S_m^{(k)}=\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{(n-1)!}{(n+k)!}$$ and using the same ideas as  David H's in his answer, we can find a nice and simple expression $$S_m^{(k)}=\frac{1}{k^2}\left(\frac{1}{\Gamma (k)}-k\,\frac{\Gamma (m+1)}{\Gamma (k+m+1)}\right)$$ which seems to be valid for any $k$ (integer or not).

If $m\to \infty$, there is convergence only if $k>0$ because of the second term in brackets (Stirling approximation shows this point easily). In such a case, $$\lim_{m\to \infty } \, S_m^{(k)}=\frac{1}{k^2\,\Gamma (k)}=\frac{1}{k\,\Gamma (k+1)}$$ which leads to David H's if $k$ is an integer.

For small values of $k$, the asymptotics is given by $$\lim_{m\to \infty } \, S_m^{(k)}=\frac{1}{k}+\gamma +\left(\frac{\gamma ^2}{2}-\frac{\pi ^2}{12}\right)
   k+O\left(k^2\right)$$